# Error with H2 not creating the schema with my data.sql file

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have this project that I just started and using a model from my teacher I created a simple class to be mapped in the H2. So far no problems I run the application and the table is generated and I try some insert commands and they are fine but when I add the **data.sql** at the resources folder the project refuses to generate the schema.

Here is my application.properties file:

```
# DATABASE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
    
# JPA
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

The SuperHero.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "super_hero")
@Data
public class SuperHero {

@Id
@Column(name="id", updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String name;
}
```

The data.sql file:

```
INSERT INTO super_hero(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Super Man');
```

This is the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script 
statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/gabri/git/plexus-super-heroes/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT 
INTO SUPER_HERO(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Super Man'); nested exception is 
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "SUPER_HERO" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO SUPER_HERO(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Super Man') [42102-200]
```

I tried to change to lowercase and upercase the table name, recreate the project from the scratch but keep getting this error.

Comment: It may happen because your application creates table "SUPER_HERO" on startup and h2 i executing data.sql script even before that. So in time of script exec this table has not yet been created.

Comment: Sounds like it but what bugs me is that I have this simple sample from the teacher that uses a USER table with Id and name and runs fine with the data.sql
I tried to change this property 
       'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop'

Comment: @GabrielVendramini do you go to `/h2-console` and check manually whether the table is created? would you, maybe, include your data.sql script that creates table? have you tried to enable logging? are other tables created or nothing gets created?.. question is lacking details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your statements in import.sql instead of data.sql and retry. Hibernate uses this file to initialize the table.

Comment: Hey, could you please what properties you set to make it running??

Comment: These, properties worked for me.
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks! After renaming the file it worked just fine. I still don't understand why in the other project with the same pom dependencies only with one is for java 1.8 and mine with java 11 this was happening.

Comment: If you still want to use data.sql you can try with this property it is needed by new Spring boot version
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
Ref : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization

Answer (score 0):

for me also import.sql works fine, I try more experiments with data.sql, I think for in-memory database models better to use import.sql

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As of SpringBoot 3.2.1 in order to specify the `schema.sql` file and `data.sql` file you can use following configurations in `application.properties`.

```
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:sql/schema.sql
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:sql/data.sql
```

As of above configuration, sql files need to be specified inside `resources/sql` directory. Note that `sql` directory is created manually inside the `resources` folder.

[image]

To control the initialization of the database `spring.sql.init.mode` configuration could be used.

Following is a sample `application.properties` file.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils=debug
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:sql/schema.sql
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:sql/data.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

More details on above configurations could be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)